# Is it reasonable to estimate the CDF of a random variable with the help of kernel density estimation?

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, cumulative-distribution-function

Given a set $S$ of samples from a random variable $X$ with pdf $f$ and cdf $F$, is it reasonable to estimate $F(x)$ by finding an estimation  $\hat{f}$ of $f$ via kernel density estimation on $S$, and calculating, using an appropriate numerical integration method, $\int_{-\infty}^{x}{\hat{f}(z)}dz$?

What I mean by "reasonable" is this: would there be any sort of general characteristics of $X$ (e.g., a high kurtosis of its pdf) that would ensure this estimate to be better than the one obtained via the empirical distribution of $X$ implied by $S$?